# How to draw route in map?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I m working with one of the marine navigator application i want to draw route on  water level like sea.Can any one please help?? I want to add annotation  and then route between two annotation...Please help..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Apple CrumbPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Listings/Classes_CrumbPath_h.html) It does what you need very nicely. I used it to draw a users path in real time.